# How to extract values from a string on ksh (korn shell)

Tags: shell, ksh

I have the following input

> 1. MyComposite[2.1], partition=default, mode=active, state=on, isDefault=true, deployedTime=2012-05-07T15:35:22.473-07:00
> 2. MessageManager[1.0], partition=default, mode=active, state=on, isDefault=true, deployedTime=2012-05-07T15:37:14.137-07:00
> 3. SimpleApproval[1.0], partition=default, mode=active, state=on, isDefault=true, deployedTime=2012-05-07T15:28:39.599-07:00

and I have a script that parses the input line by line from a file but I don't have a clue on how I could extract individual parameters from each line into local variables so I can perform additional processes

So far I'm trying the following:

```
#!/bin/ksh

file="output"

compositeName="foo" ci=0
# while loop while read line do
        # display line or do somthing on $line
        if echo "$line" | egrep -q '\[[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\].*?(mode=active).*?
           (state=on)'  then compositeName=$( echo "$line" | egrep '[0-9]*' ) 
        echo "$compositeName" 
               #echo "$line"
        fi
         done <"$file"
```

I'm somwhow lookint to extract only two values from this string, the first word and the float between brackets

ie:

> name = MyComposite 
>   version = 2.1

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if those line numbers are in the file or not. If not, you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

while IFS="," read nameVersion line; do
  name="${nameVersion%%\[*}"
  version="${nameVersion//*\[+([0-9.])\]*/\1}"
  print "name=$name version=$version"
done < "$file"
```

If the line numbers *are* in the file, change the name assignment in the above script to `name="${nameVersion//+([0-9]).+( )+(*)\[*/\3}"`

Comment: Yes, those line numbers are in the file and are not consecutive. now I need to validate each line that matches the format with egrep as many lines in the file are useless, do you think I could skip lines that are not in the format with your approach?